# How to edit a file instead of creating a new one using MediaStore above Android 10?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-10.0

I've tried to create a file in Documents external directory using MediaStore with the above code :

```
        val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "doc.txt")
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain")
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Documents")
        }

        val uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), contentValues)

        uri?.let {
            resolver.openOutputStream(it).use {
                // Write file
                it?.write("line1".toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset()))
                it?.write("line2".toByteArray(Charset.defaultCharset()))
                it?.close()
            }

        }
```

The first time I execute this code, the file *'doc.txt'* is created like expected.

But if I execute the same code again, it create me a new file *'doc (1).txt'* instead of editing the file I already created.

How can I modify the original *'doc.txt'* file when it already exist ?

In my understanding, I should be able to write on this file because I created it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But if I execute the same code again, it create me a new file 'doc (1).txt' instead of editing the file I already created.

Your code does two things:

- Inserts a new entry into the `MediaStore`
- Opens an `OutputStream` for the `Uri` returned by `insert()` and writes content to that stream

If you do not not want a new entry, do not insert one.

> How can I modify the original 'doc.txt' file when it already exist ?

Open an `OutputStream` for the `Uri` that you were given originally, and write content to that stream.